# Python issue running subprocess.Popen() from a .py in console

Tags: bash, python-3.x, shell, subprocess, popen

I am running a program which uses subprocess.Popen() in order to do some tasks (I cannot use os.system() for them). The program, which correctly runs within an IDE (I will explain later) stops when I run it from the console, although I can resume it by writing `fg` in the console.

The code is the following (this is a piece of code,the full code implements similar tasks to which the same problem occurs)...

```
import subprocess


p,o = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', '-i', 'which python3.5'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
p = p.decode('ascii')
print(p)


print('Installing pysamstats...')
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', '-i', 'conda install -y -c bioconda     pysamstats']).communicate()
print('OK')
```

If the code is run from an IDE (I use PyCharm with anaconda as interpreter) the output occurs and all the script runs smoothly, with the exception that the following message appears each time Popen is called...

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (3556): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

With the exception of the "error", as I have said, the code is correctly executed.

However, if I run the .py file from the console...

```
python3 '/DIRTOFILE/ZZZ.py'
```

The following message appears...

```
/home/labcombio1/anaconda3/bin/python3.5

Installing pysamstats...

[1]+  Stopped                 python3 '/media/labcombio1/ZZZ.py'
```

That is, the first command is executed, and the output is correctly printed, whereas the second command is stopped. If I resume the command with `fg`, it works fine. The same happens if the first Popen command is not run, that is, only with the second one.

I have tried `shell=True`, removing `.communicate()`, adding `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, and none of these things solves the "Stopped" line at the console. Other commands yield the same results.

Finally, I have tried running the following commands:

```
subprocess.Popen('conda install -y -c bioconda pysamstats', shell=True).communicate()

subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'conda install -y -c bioconda     pysamstats']).communicate()
```

And although they both work correctly in Pycharm (they don't even prompt `bash: cannot set terminal process group (3556): Inappropriate ioctl for device`), the terminal still fails, with the following message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found
```

I know little about subprocess module, and despite reading other questions and some pages taking about it, I have been unable to solve that problem.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First *problem*:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (3556): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Remove `-i` flag from `bash`interpreter.

> -i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.

Example:

```
p, o = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'which python3.5'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Second issue:

```
/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found
```

The `conda`path is not exported in your environment.

**Possible Solutions**

1) Load it in your IDE.

2) Use the full path to the executable.

```
subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/conda/conda', 'install', '-y', '-c', 'bioconda', 'pysamstats']).communicate()
```

3) Pass an `env` to `Popen`.

```
subprocess.Popen(['conda', 'install', '-y', '-c', 'bioconda', 'pysamstats'], env={"PATH": "/path/to/conda"}).communicate()
```

Comment: As I have stated in my question, by doing this the problem remains, it throws the message: "/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found" in the terminal.

Comment: Hi, the recommendations you mentioned worked to some extent. The problem now is that if I need to call subprocess.Popen again, it gets also stopped. It looks as if the process is not fully terminated, and it gets stopped or something.