# Issue with subprocess.Popen() pipeline

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

Regarding a previous question which was partially solved ([Python issue running subprocess.Popen() from a .py in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654645/python-issue-running-subprocess-popen-from-a-py-in-console)). I still find some errors to which I cannot give a solution.

The important part of the code is the following:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash','-c', '-i', 'which conda'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
conda_location = proc.stdout.read().decode('ascii')
conda_location = conda_location[:-1]
print('ANACONDA LOCATION: ', conda_location)

#some stuff

print('Checking presence of HOMER files...')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', '-i', 'which findMotifs.pl'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = proc.stdout.read().decode('ascii')
p = p[:-1]

#more stuff
```

If I run this code in PyCharm IDE console, it runs without any problem. However, if I run it within the Linux terminal, the following happens:

[image]

Now, if I switch the processes, the second process (now the first) runs, and the first process (now the second) gets stopped. Also, if I run each process independently, they work fine.

This findings make me think that is probable that the first process is waiting, and the second process gets stopped. However, when I run `proc.wait()`, `proc.kill()` or `proc.terminate()`, none of the actions make the second function to work correctly, and still gets stopped.

I have also tried adding `.communicate()` or `shell=True`, but to no avail.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Python issue, but rather a bash issue.

Giving bash the `-i` (interactive) flag tells bash that it is interactive, i.e., it should read input from stdin and execute any commands entered.  (Of course, first it runs the `-c` command you gave it—but *after*....)

Bash's stdin is the same as Python's stdin, since you did not redirect it.  So bash attempts to read from stdin.  In itself, this would not be that bad—but bash also does *job control*, which means it has to take over the allocation of processes, process groups, and so on, to make sure that only *one pipeline* (`prog1 | prog2 | prog3`) *at a time* can read from the terminal.  Bash therefore attempts to wrest control of the terminal away from your Python session, where your *outer* shell passed control to that Python session.

The result is a `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOU` or `SIGTSTP` signal (the details vary from one OS to another; it looks like Linux gave you a SIGTSTP but my BSD experiment got a `SIGTTIN`; see http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux for more on these) and general poor behavior as the various processes fight over who is allowed to do what, when, to the session.

The simplest cure is the same as you were told before: drop the `-i` flag.

If `-i` is making the program find-able when it is otherwise *not* find-able, you have configured your environment incorrectly, e.g., by setting `PATH` only in `~/.bashrc` even though `bash` is not your primary shell (your `PATH` setting should be in `~/.profile` if your primary shell is `sh`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have been trying but to no avail. First, as you have said, I removed the `-i` flag and, as you mentioned, it did not worked completely, so I added the PATH to `~/.profile` and it did not work either. If I get it to work completely, I will post the answer.

Comment: "Where to set `$PATH`" can be a problem on its own. There's no single right answer, as it's situation-dependent. (The same applies to `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path` in Python itself, although those have nothing to do with this issue, I just mean that the general problem, "where to configure a path", generally applies to many general situations, generally. :-) )

Comment: Yeah, but what I don't really see here is that if I set my path in bashrc and load the command from the Terminal, it works. If I load the command from PyCharm (with '-i') it works. If I load the command with '-i' from the .py file on the terminal, it also works, but once! (any other command will cause it to stop). Therefore, I guess the problem is not only with the command or the location of the PATH itself (because of running without '-i', but with the problem of communication of subprocess.Popen. Still, I cannot believe I am the first person who experiences this kind of problem...

Comment: I don't recommend this, as you're papering over the real problem (which is some sort of faulty PATH setting), but: you can defeat bash's reading of stdin by making its stdin point to `/dev/null` (or whatever the local OS-equivalent is), by adding `stdin=` to the `Popen`. I am not sure how, or even if, this works on Windows, but on Unix/Linux/BSD, `os.open` `os.devnull` and pass the resulting file descriptor as the `stdin=` argument. Then you can retain the `-i` flag, which should force bash to read `~/.bash_profile` to set its PATH.

Comment: Well, I've tried this and although it recognizes the PATH, it stops again... so we are back to the roots. The problem with the faulty PATH, even if this is true, is that the program will be distributed, so any user on any computer should be able to run it without problems. I have other strategies to "solve" the issue, but it is bugging me a lot because I find this is the "cleanest" one. Is there any other way to obtain a path to a program without using subprocess.Popen() or similars?

Comment: There are two usual approaches: (1) Don't try to find the thing at all. *Require* that the user configure an appropriate path. This is very flexible and works well but requires action by the users, which frustrates users. (2) Code your own path-searching using locations you know (and possibly extra locations that are configurable by users), then use the known path. This is inflexible, often works well enough, and frustrates users when it doesn't. :-)

Comment: Yeah... Your second choice was the alternative way of working the problem I thought of... although it's really frustrating. Thank you for the help anyway!